# ISOdate/POSIXct vs Milliseconds

Tags: database, date, datetime, storage

This is more of a thinking question.
I have been working around different time/date formats, and I noticed that it seems to be preferred to store date/time objects as variables with unique classes (like ISOdate or POSIXct) in databases (like Mongo, MySQL, postegen).

I get why one would want to convert to such a format when analyzing data, but I was wondering what's the advantage for when I store it in that format in a data-base?

Do these formats tend to take less space than conventional numbers?
I can't seem to find an answer online.

Comment: The underlying storage is likely to be similar.  The classes tend to make formatting and analysis easier.  Note that even though you have to type 2015-05-29 as a string, the classes probably turn that into an appropriate integer before storing it on disk.  It probably won't occupy 10 bytes; it might only occupy 4 bytes for a pure date.  Distinguish between the display formats and the storage formats (both on-disk and in-memory).  The three may be very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arguments sake let's just talk about a simple `date` type (just date, no time or time zone) - such as the `DATE` type in MySQL.

Say we stored a string of `2014-12-31`.  What's one day later?  As a human, it's easy to come up with the answer `2015-01-01`, but a computer needs to have those algorithms programmed in.

While these types might expose APIs that have the algorithms for dealing with calendar math, under the hood they most likely store the information as a whole number of days since some starting date (which is called an "epoch").  So `2014-12-31` is actually stored as something like `16701`.  The computer can very efficiently add 1 to get `16702` for the next day.

This also makes it much easier to sort.  Sure, in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, the lexicographical sort order is preserved, but it still takes much more processing power to sort strings than it does integers.  Also, the date might be formatted for other cultures when represented as a string, such as in `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD/MM/YYYY` format, which are *not* lexicographically sortable.  If you through thousands of dates into a table and then query with a `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` clause, the database needs to be able to efficiently sort the values, and integer sorting is much faster than analyzing strings.

And yes - they tend to take much less physical storage space as well.

The same principles apply when date and time are both present, and you also have to contend with the precision of the time value (seconds, milliseconds, nanoseconds, etc.)

Comment: I wasn't arguing over the YYYY-DD-MM format, but rather storing it as Miliseconds, which seems to be like less storage intensive

Comment: They ultimately are stored as numeric or custom binary under the hood.  The data type is there to provide an API that works with dates, wrapping the logic of going from date to number and back without you having to do it yourself.